# Android urlConnection issues

Tags: java, android, json

I'm having issues with notification not always being sent out with my Android App.

Rather than fixing a bug I'd just like to know the possibilities of the urlConnection.

My app sends off the url www.example.com?U=1234 then that php page checks the database userIDs for U, if U is found to exist then it marks a column as "1" signalling that this user has been checked by my app and echos out the username. My java then gets the echo'd out data and does something if it isn't null. This is just an example but the logic is identical. This check happens once every minute. If a notification is not sent the database however is still updated with a "1" meaning a user was found and the querystring worked, just no notification was sent out.

In my testing environment and my phone this works 100% of the time, I've checked over 30 times in every single phone state I can think of. However sometimes for seemingly random reasons I get no notifications when out in the day.

My question is: in areas with a poor internet connection or bad mobile data, is it possible for this logic to send off the querystring, find the user, mark the column as "1" and echoing out the username but the connection is too weak to read the returned username in time resulting in no notification?

Would it be better to send the querystring and get the returned username, check in java if the url returned anything, and THEN send another querystring to update the column as "1" and alert a notification if this urlConnection was successful? This would keep checking if internet connection was lost until both the username was returned and the column was marked as "1" whereas the first logic does everything at once meaning there is no real failsafe.

Or I'm completely wrong and it's something else. Either way any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing however I think what you are looking for is when the urlConnection is not successful log that has failed to an external text file.

Depends on how your backend has been set up.

Comment: I agree it's confusing. However, it seems to be that urlConnection is always successful as the database still updates. It's just the returning string sometimes isn't returned. I think the only way for my setup is to check the string is returned then do another urlConnection to update the database. Meaning that even if it fails for an unknown reason it'll try again a minute later until successful..

Comment: Why are you keeping urlConnections open? The best way is to use async connections.